# Why do these objects appear to scatter across the screen?

Tags: physics

I'm trying physics in blender for the first time. I have the keys set in a floating position, and I'd like them to rest as they would in real life.

[image: The keys, as they are now.]

I've added a dynamic rigid body to each of the keys, with a mass of 0.008 kg. The keyring has a rigid body as well, but I've unchecked the dynamic checkbox, per a tutorial.

[image: A view of a key's physics settings.]

Unfortunately, the keys appear to explode across the screen when I hit play:

[image: The keys scattering across the screen.]

Someone suggested I turn down the sensitivity margin from the default, but using 0 nor 0.001 has made a difference.

What's wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This type of collision is really hard to calculate, so rigid bodies might not work well. Hopefully you don't need it for an animation, because it would be a lot easier to just position the keys by hand